# Is there an API that gives you near realtime stock portfolio holdings?

Tags: api, finance, plaid

I am trying to find an API similar to https://plaid.com/ that allows users to connect to multiple brokerages and return security holding information. The issue with Plaid seems to be that they only provide updates once a day and I am looking for something more "real time."

Has anyone come across another service like this that provides up-to-date information on your portfolio?